# Weird behaviour when removeItemAtPath and copyItemAtPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to make sure removeItemAtPath is completed before executing the copyItemAtPath function?

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:newDocpath]){
    //removing file
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:newDocpath error:&deleteError]){
        NSLog(@"Could not remove old files. Error:%@",deleteError);
    }
}

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath: pathToPDF toPath: newDocpath error: &copyError]
```

Is there a possibility of items not remove or copied since I'm placing the above-mentioned functions in a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

`removeItemAtPath` works quasi synchronously. From the documentation

> **Return Value**
>
> `YES` if the item **was** removed successfully or if URL was `nil`. Returns `NO` if an error occurred. If the delegate stops the operation for a file, this method returns `YES`. However, if the delegate stops the operation for a directory, this method returns `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `removeItemAtPath:error:`
**Removes the file or directory at the specified path.

First I start from [fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1410277-fileexistsatpath?language=objc)

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a file or directory
>   exists at a specified path. The isDirectory out parameter indicates
>   whether the path points to a directory or a regular file.

**Returns**

> `YES` if a file at the specified path exists, or `NO` if the file’s does
>   not exist or its existence could not be determined.

Then

[removeItemAtPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1408573-removeitematpath)

> Removes the file or directory at the specified path.

***What does it return?***

> It returns `YES` if the item was removed successfully or if path was
>   nil. Returns `NO` if an error occurred. If the delegate stops the
>   operation for a file, this method returns `YES`. However, if the
>   delegate stops the operation for a directory, this method returns `NO`.